# Python, Need Long Value to be Integer

Tags: python, json, rest, int, long-integer

I'm trying to insert a unix timestamp using REST to a webservice.  And when I convert the dictionary I get the value: 1392249600000L  I need this value to be an integer.

So I tried `int(1392249600000L)` and I get `1392249600000L`, still a long value.

The reason I need this is because the JSON webservice only accepts timestamsp with milliseconds in them, but when I pass the JSON value with the 'L' in it I get an invalid JSON Primative of value `1392249600000L` error.

Can someone please help me resolve this?  It seems like it should be so easy, but it's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 3):

You should not be using Python representations when you are sending JSON data. Use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to represent integers instead:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(1392249600000L)
'1392249600000'
```

In any case, the `L` is only part of the string *representation* to make debugging easier, making it clear you have a `long`, not `int` value. Don't use Python string representations for network communications, in any case.

For example, if you have a *list* of Python values, the `str()` representation of that list will also use `repr()` representations of the *contents* of the list, resulting in `L` postfixes for `long` integers. But `json.dumps()` handles such cases properly too, *and* handle other types correctly too (like Python `None` to JSON `null`, Python `True` to JSON `true`, etc.):

```
>>> json.dumps([1392249600000L, True, None])
'[1392249600000, true, null]'
```

Comment: interesting, so if I'm doing a post with these values and urlencoding, who I have to account for anything else?

Comment: Are you sending a JSON post, or are you sending a URL encoded post? Because in the latter case you'd use the [`urllib.urlencode()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) instead, which handles that style of encoding properly. You didn't share code, but did imply that the REST service expected JSON data.